# Which one is correct? "Look here" or "Look at here"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Between the following two phrases:

- "Look here"
- "Look at here"

which one is correct?

Is it advisable to use "at" in this case?

Comment: "At" is a preposition, and is nearly always followed by a noun phrase. As Robusto helpfully points out, there are occasional cases where "here" functions as a noun phrase, but as a rule it does not, so "at" cannot precede it.

Comment: "Lookee here" is what may be being said when you think you hear "look at here".

Comment: You can’t be serious!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Look here" is correct. I would never use "Look at here" all by itself, but in sentences such as "There's not much to look at here" or "There are many things to look at here" it is certainly grammatical. Also, it is perfectly grammatical to say "Look at this".

Comment: +1: But you left out cases like "Consider adverbs of place: specifically, look at *here*." (And, yes, I'm just messing with you.)

Comment: @RegDwigнt♦ Can it be said without "at"? "Let's have a look (at) the way those sentences have structured."

Answer (score 2):

It is incorrect to use *at* in this case. You could say any of the following in the imperative sense:

> - Look here
> - Look *at* this
> - Look *at* this place

Comment: What about "look over here."

Answer (score 2):

"Look at here!" isn't certainly correct.

Comment: "certainly isn't" is not the same as "isn't certainly".  The former says "I am *certain* this isn't correct" while the latter says "I'm not sure, it may be correct, or it might not be".

Comment: You guys are just awesome.. (Please don't comment that "just awesome" is not same as "awesome")..

Answer (score -3):

"Look over here" also works. "Look here" can also mean "See here, Mr. Smith..." which has a tone of command.