# The question about this word "there"

Tags: grammar

As I know, the word "there" has been used as an adverb a lot.

But it's also a noun. Not only can you say "What are you doing there?" but "What are you doing in there?" also works. But what about "at there"?

I was checking some homework from a few kids in my work.
There was this question: What did he get at the supermarket?

Nearly all the kids wrote "He got some apples at there." 
I've never heard people say that, but I'm not quite sure if it's grammatically correct but people just don't say it, or it's just ungrammatical.

Comment: Answered at ["In here", "from here", and "at here"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/219978/in-here-from-here-and-at-here) and the linked thread.

Answer (score -1):

It is not correct, and shouldn't be used:

`There` (as a preposition used with stative meaning) means `at that place`. You wouldn't say: `I met him at at that place.`

Comment: If you look at the threads linked to above, you will see the standard of answers considered good on ELU. Unsupported statements, even if correct or broadly correct, usually come across as mere opinion (and may be just that).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you - I guess that answers based on common sense, and experience, rather than dictionary references and lengthy discourses, are, shall we say, not up to the standards of ELU? I can live with that... each place has its own rules.

Comment: The trouble is that even university professors have been known to disagree on what is right never mind on the best way to explain _why_ it is right, so people just claiming that their answers are based on common sense and experience are not being very scholarly. If you check at the Help Center say, you'll see what the recommendations are.