# Why does CGEL call "home", "abroad", "here", and "there" prepositions instead of adverbs like dictionaries say?

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis, adverbs, parts-of-speech

We know that the words *home, abroad, here,* and *there* are **adverbs** because
the dictionaries all say so.

But in [*The Cambridge Grammar of the English
Language*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language)
(GGEL), authors Huddleston and Pullum tell us that well no, actually they
are **prepositions**. (!)

1. How and why does CGEL call these words prepositions? Does anybody else?
2. Are there ways to still use these words as adverbs even
   if CGEL now considers them prepositions?

Comment: Related (*home*): https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/511146/is-the-word-home-never-an-adverb and (for *here*): https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/219978/in-here-from-here-and-at-here

Comment: And some regard them as a different part of speech altogether. An analogue of determiners. (Have you noticed that 'determiner' is now being recognised by some dictionaries as a part of speech that 50 years ago they would not have considered? It takes them a while to adjust to modern analyses. Which are themselves ongoing.)

Comment: We know that the words _home, abroad, here_, and _there_ are **prepositions**  because  authors Huddleston and Pullum, in The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (GGEL), tell us so. But in some dictionaries, compilers tell us that well no, actually they are **adverbs**. (!!)

Comment: If it helps, Pullam claims "because" is a preposition at https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?cat=38. The response to the original claim is here: https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=9494

Answer (score 4):

In an article published on Geoffrey Pullum's website, "[The Theoretical Orientation of The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/%7Egpullum/CGELtheory.pdf)," Pullum and Rodney Huddleston provide a succinct defense of their redefinition of preposition. In short, Pullum and Huddleston find that the conventional definition of *prepositions* arbitrarily groups similar usages under other categories of speech (like adverb and conjunction); it makes sense for them to consider words applied to all of these uses as *prepositions*.

Consider this extended excerpt, where the authors present the way that a similarly-appearing word may be classified in three different ways with only slight changes:

> It is also clear that uncontroversial prepositions like in, up, down,
> over, through, etc., are sometimes not followed by a noun (or NP) or
> anything at all:
>
> - Soon they went in the house.
> - Soon they went in.
> - He came running up the street.
> - He came running up.
> - Does this hole go right through the wall?
> - Does this hole go right through?
> - They like to run around the yard.
> - They like to run around.
>
> To take account of such facts,
> traditional grammar posits that a substantial subset of the
> prepositions have homophonous and virtually synonymous doppelgangers
> belonging to other categories. Thus they recognize the word down as a
> preposition in *He fell down the steps* (it is followed by the NP *the
> stairs*) but not in *He fell down on the steps*. In the latter, since
> there is no NP following it, *down* has to be an adverb (it does, after
> all, modify the verb *fell*). Another (overlapping) subset are alleged
> to have doppelgangers in the ‘subordinating conjunction’ category: in
> *before her court appearance* the word *before* is acknowledged as a
> preposition, but in *before she appeared in court*, where what follows
> *before* is a declarative content clause, it is claimed not to be.
>
> **There is no semantic, morphological, or phonological support for having three words spelled *before*.** (emphasis mine on the last sentence)

The second of each example shows that "uncontroversial prepositons" already can appear in positions where they do not *pre-pose* or appear before any NP (noun phrase) at all. Why are other words, otherwise similar in how they appear in a sentence, grouped as adverbs or conjunctions instead?

To your question, I find the last example, "I like to run around," especially useful, because that sounds fairly close to the question you are raising with *home*. *Around* and *home* both have directional senses. If *around* here is a preposition, and you accept that not all prepositions have to precede NP, then why can't *home* function in a similar way as *a preposition that doesn't have to precede an NP*? So in *I like to run home*, *home* functions as an *intransitive preposition* (a preposition that takes no NP complement) rather than an adverb.

There is more to why Huddleston and Pullum categorize words as they do, for which I recommend a more careful reading of *CGEL*. Huddleston and Pullum are only one of several opinions on *home* - the traditional grammarians they are responding to still exist, for example.

Comment: 'The ferry docks right beside the road, a mile before one reaches Elbonia City. We knew we had plenty of time before it sailed. Arriving at the quay where the ferry was docked with over six hours to spare, we drove on.' Arguably, one sense of 'drove on' here looks very un-intransitive-prepositiony.

Comment: *Huddleston and Pullum tell us that well no, actually they are prepositions.* Huddleston and Pullum tend to be rather "avant garde" and iconoclasts - I suspect that that is how they made their name. I find many of their explanations somewhat tortuous and often appear to be procrustean (i.e. enforcing uniformity or conformity without regard to natural variation or individuality.) They also give the appearance of being apologists. Nevertheless, they command a dedicated following. **home, abroad, here, and there are adverbs.**

Comment: @Greybeard While I personally agree, I answered the question as I did because the focus is on CGEL and why it classifies as it does, rather than what I think of CGEL.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin I have no difficulty with your answer - it's good, but my comment was no more than a general caveat.

Comment: They're being good descriptivists, putting lexical items into lexical categories by the usual rules, but applied generously. For instance, the idea of intransitive prepositions is a good use of an unused category; nobody applied transitivity to any other category beside verbs (and participles, if one sticks with [the original eight](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/don.html)). It works just as well for prepositions, which already have objects, so they're automatically transitive, leaving the intransitive uses free for phrasal and idiomatic use.

Comment: This is indeed a very helpful answer to the first part of the question (why do they classify these words as prepositions?), but it needs to be supplemented by Greybeard's comment, which responds more explicitly to the second part ('Does anybody else?'). Part of the OP's puzzlement is probably caused by the book in question being sold and marketed as *The Cambridge Grammar*, which may create an illusion that the authority of the whole of the university somehow stands behind it. It would have been more honest and less misleading if it had been sold as 'Huddleston and Pullum's Grammar'.