# Why are location words like "here" adverbs rather than adjectives?

Tags: adverbs, parts-of-speech

In learning another language, I realized that in English, location-related words are adverbs, not adjectives like I expected.

> "I'm cold/tall/fast/young" - these words are adjectives, modifying "I"
>
> "I'm here/around/behind/inside" - these words are adverbs, so they modify "am"?

My main question is "why aren't these adjectives?"

In case that's too general, here are the related points that come to mind:

- is there a simple concept or test sentence that would clarify the difference? I'm guessing "I am" is the most confusing example.
- is it true that this applies to all/most location-related words? what makes location special? or is that just how the language developed?
- are there any other classes of words like this? I checked out time-related words, like "I'm early/late", but I think those are adjectives in that usage, is that right?

Related answers that don't do it for me:

- [What part of speech does “here” have in “I am here”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111058/what-part-of-speech-does-here-have-in-i-am-here)
- https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/197217/here-adverb-or-adjective

Comment: The adjectives "cold/tall/fast/young" and the locatives "here/around/behind/inside" are not modifiers but **complements** of "be", the first four being predicative, the others non-predicative. Trad grammar classifies the locatives as adverbs, while modern grammar classifies them as prepositions, for example "here" has the prepositional interpretation "in some place". The locatives fail all the tests for adjectivehood, for example they can't be modified by "very" and nor can they be complement to complex-transitive verbs or complexintransitive ones. Does that help?

Comment: @BillJ Yes! That's a good, concise summary, except maybe for the end of the first sentence. Why aren't the locatives predicative? Also, thanks for mentioning they're called "locatives"! Other answers didn't mention that.

Comment: The received wisdom suggests that although assigning a location to something is comparable to assigning it a property, there are numerous verbs that take only one or the other of the two kinds of complements, i.e. predicative or locative. For example, "became" can take adjectival complements ("He became anxious") but not locative complements (*"He became in the city centre"). Similarly, we can have "KIm seemed angry", but not *"Kim seemed at the back of the queue". It is for this reason that the locatives are not assimilated to the predicatives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As John Lawler said in the answer to the first-linked question, calling “here” an adverb is not actually very useful for understanding how it functions in English.

In fact, there is more similarity between the behavior of *here, home, at the park* than there is between the behavior of *here, carefully, very,* despite the fact that conventional part of speech categorization calls *carefully* and *very* adverbs also.

Because *here* behaves similarly to prepositional phrases like *at the park,* it can be analyzed as belonging to the same part of speech as prepositions. This makes “preposition” a misnomer for the category (since “here” is not proposed to anything), but the [*Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* uses *preposition* as the label for the set of location-describing words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/547159/why-does-cgel-call-home-abroad-here-and-there-prepositions-instead-of) that encompasses traditional prepositions despite the mismatch with the term’s etymology.

It’s hard to explain why languages make the language-specific categorizations and generalizations that they do. You can say that it is because of analogies between words with similar meanings, but clearly the same analogies have not applied in all languages.

There are similarities in behavior between prepositional phrases (in the CGEL sense) and adjective phrases, but also differences. Both can be used as predicates or to modify nominal phrases. But prepositional phrases generally cannot be placed in the pre-nominal attributive position: we can say *the blue house* but not **the here house*. This test shows that *early* and *late* exist as adjectives.

Comment: Hmm, I don't mind that they're specifically adverbs as much as I mind that they're not adjectives. I updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: It's not the languages that makes those categorizations. It's the grammarians, and the notion of there being a limited number (traditionally 8, but not always the same 8) of categories for words  comes from the Greeks and Romans, who were not talking about English, since it didn't exist. So you don't have to worry about whether they're adverbs or not. What they are in these examples are locative predicates. If you'd rather call them prepositions or participials, that's between you and your confessor.

Comment: @JohnLawler fascinating point! I was going to say that POS (needn't be just the ol' 8) are important for knowing how to use the words. But in this particular case, I probably already know the usage differences from practice, and the sentence "I'm x" was just muddying the waters for me.

Comment: To say that *at the park* is a preposition phrase is to say something about what it contains -- it says nothing about the context that contains it. By contrast, *here* resembles *at the park* in that they are an adverb of place and an adverbial phrase of place -- this resemblance has nothing to do with what the phrase contains. So why call *here* a preposition?

Comment: @JohnLawler Your point of view appears to me to be diverging excessively from the norm. Grammarians do not "make" categories but instead recognize them in language on the basis of objective criteria. For instance, a grammarian does not tell you that "white" is an adjective because of a fancy of his but because he can't help but notice that "white" occurs attributively (white bread, white gown, white pawn, white paint,…) whereas "here" does not (not normally, "this here sth" is not usual, https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=).

Comment: @LPH No, grammarians **claim** they recognize them, but in order to make that claim, they have to (a) define the category they are claiming, (b) provide convincing syntactic tests to distinguish them from everything else, and (c) provide convincing counterarguments to all the arguments against it. There is no "the norm"; there are authorities, like CGEL or McCawley or Quirk or Jespersen, but they differ, as they should, since they use different theories and therefore claim to see different things. Oh, and you may not have noticed that I am a grammarian and therefore don't need to be told this.

Comment: @JohnLawler In fact further search shows that "here" might be attaining to the "rank" of adjective: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22this%20here%20book%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en.

Comment: @JohnLawler Agreed, the authorities differ, but hardly ever in a way that is too controversial; they are all necessarily forced to come to the same fundamental conclusions, they can't escape the facts, as those for instance that point at the difference between a noun and an adjective.

Comment: "Noun" and "adjective" are not facts of nature that can be discovered. As I said before, they are parts of a descriptive system, a theory. If one develops a theory that uses these terms, one must provide complete descriptions and arguments for them. Let me be the first to assure you that grammarians **often** disagree, on just about everything, certainly about the nature of lexical categories. Note, for instance, that CGEL holds an extreme minority position in terms of how much of it is accepted by English-speaking grammarians. I like some of the ideas, but not most, and I'm not that unusual.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm obviously less knowledgeable than you all, but your comment seems dismissive to me. Maybe they're not facts of nature, but aren't they facts in some sense? There *are* patterns in English, and speakers *do* need to follow those patterns to communicate. I'm sure the details get fuzzy, but the authorities agree on the broad strokes, no?

Comment: Call it dismissive if you like. I was merely repeating the same thing I said above, which was dismissed as "diverging excessively from the norm", without any reference. This is not how grammar is done. There are patterns in English, yes, but the authorities do not agree on the broad strokes, no. Certainly not on the ones at issue in this question. Lexical categories, I repeat, are not themselves facts; rather, they're analyses, and must be argued for with factual evidence.

Comment: Lawler's comments are more philosophical than practical and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As far as "type of word", semantically, "here" is an adverb.
An adverb's primary function is to qualify a verb.

*We will play here tomorrow.*

Syntactically, i.e., as far as what function it fulfills in the sentence, "here" can be:

**1 - A "circumstantial complement of place".**

Complements of time are a part of the sentence's predicate that qualifies the predicate's nucleus, (which is normally a verb), place-wise.

For example, in the sentence above,  *We will play here tomorrow.*:

- "*We*" is the subject
- "*will play here tomorrow*" is the predicate, and within the predicate:

  - "*will play*" is the verbal nucleus
  - "*here*" is a circumstantial complement of place
  - "*tomorrow*" is a circumstantial complement of time

"Circumstantial complement" is not the only function that an adverbs can fulfill (although it is the most important).

**2 - An attribute (qualifier)  of an adjective (or attribute construction)**

*The insects present here  belong to a new species.*

In the above example:

- "*belong to a new species*"  is the predicate
- "*The insects present here*" is the subject, and within the subject

  - "*insects*" is the nominal nucleus
  - "*the*" is an attribute (of the nucleus)
  - "*present here*" is an attribute (of the nucleus), and inside it:

    - "*present*" is the nucleus (of that adjectival construction)
    - "*here*" is an attribute (of "*present*")

**3 - An attribute (qualifier)  of another adverb (or circumstantial construction)**

*We resumed of operations starting  here.*

In the above example:

- "*We*" is the subject
- "*resumed of operations starting  her*e" is the predicate, and within it:

  - "*resumed*" is the verbal nucleus

    - "*our operations*" is a direct object
    - "*starting here*" is a circumstantial complement of mode (idicating how we are resuming)

      - "*starting*" is the (adverbial) nucleus of said construction
      - "*here*" is an attribute of "starting"

**4 - A mandatory predicative**

An exception of all the above is with copulative verbs, i.e. with verbs that have little meaning on their own and mandatorily need a complement.

In that case, whatever follows a copulative verb is by definition a "mandatory predicative", regardless of the type of word.

*I am a good person.*

*He is here.*

In the above examples, because "to be" is a copulative verb, both "*a good person*", and "*here*" are mandatory, subjective predicatives (despite being very different kinds  of constructions, semantically speaking).

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of the particular language you consider. There is no variation to speak of for fundamental words, for instance, among European languages, words such as nouns and verbs; I mean by that that if the word that refers to a material object is a noun in one language it is also a noun in the other languages, as "*messer*" is a noun in German, "*knife*" is a noun in English, "*couteau*" is a noun in French and "*cuchillo*" a noun in Spanish, the four words referring to the same thing.
As the nature of the word becomes more difficult to grasp conceptually, which makes the word  likely to be associated in various ways with other words, differences begin to be manifest among the various languages. As time goes by a more or less definite usage is confirmed and the word acquires a status which is characteristic of the language in which you find it.

For instance, the word "here" cannot normally be found in attributive position in English, yet there is a tendency, although rather negligible,  to consider that it can, as  many books show ([this here book](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22this%20here%20book%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en), [this here house](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22this+here+house%22&lr=lang_en&safe=active&tbs=lr:lang_1en,sbd:1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0lM6CqqnvAhXK3YUKHTTJB4gQpwUIJA&biw=1920&bih=1005&dpr=1)). In French, for instance, there is as yet absolutely no possibility to use "here" ("ici") as an adjective, which shows that where the nature of the word is difficult to make out, language decides, so to speak.

However, we should say in familiar terms that "here" is not yet much of an adjective in English. We can understand that grammatically by considering what defines an adjective, and by doing so we will have gained the idea that the mere label "adjective" in a dictionary is not the identification of a hard and fast category; such a word is some  of the time  less than an ideal adjective. To see that we refer to CoGEL's study of the class of adjectives; it is shown that there exists what is called a gradient between the quintessential adjective and adverb. (The line "**7'**" is not part of the table; I inserted it as an illustration for further discussion to follow.)

> CoGEL *Table 7.3*
> Criteria for establishing adjective classes
> **(a)** attributive use
> **(b)** predicative use after the copula *seem*
> **(c)** premodification by *very*
> **(d)** comparison

> |  |  | **(a)** | **(b)** | **(c)** | **(d)** | feature | class |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | [1] | *hungry* | + | + | + | + | central | ADJECTIVES |
> | [2] | *infinite* | + | + | - | - | " | " |
> | [3] | *old* | + | - | + | + | peripheral | " |
> | [4] | *afraid* | ? | + | + | + | " | " |
> | [5] | *utter* | + | - | - | - | " | " |
> | [6] | *asleep* | - | + | - | - | " | " |
> | [7] | *soon* | - | - | + | + |  | ADVERBS |
> | [**7'**] | **here** | -(+) | - | - | - |  | " |
> | [8] | *abroad* | - | - | - | - |  | " |

> CoGEL, § 7.4
> If we examine *Table* 7.3, we see that [1] *hungry* alone satisfies all four criteria; [2] *infinite* accepts (a) and (b); […] [8] satisfies none of the four criteria.
>  Criterion (c), acceptance of premodification by *very*, and criterion (d), the ability to take comparison, have no diagnostic value in distinguishing adjectives from adverbs. Those two features generally coincide for a particular word, and are determined by a semantic feature, gradability, which cuts across word classes. Thus, as we can see in the table, the adverb *soon* is gradable, just like the central adjective *hungry*. […] We consider the ability of functioning both attributively and predicatively to be central features of the adjectives.
> Words like *hungry* and *infinite*, which satisfy both of these criteria (a *and* b)  are called CENTRAL adjectives.
> Words like *old, afraid, utter,* and *asleep*, which satisfy at least one of these first two criteria (a *or* b), are called PERIPHERAL adjectives.

The usage shown above concerning "here" must be examined more seriously. We see that this usage coincides with a preceding demonstrative,"*this*".

[image]

["**the** here book" and "**the** here house"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+here+book%2Cthe+here+house&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=), as well as ["**a** here book" and "**a** here house"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+here+book%2Ca+here+house&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=) are not found. Thus, if we are to consider "here" according to the scheme of definition in CoGEL we are bound to say that the word does shows perceptibly the nature of an adjective but remains only very marginally an adjective and is still uniquely an adverb.

Essentially the answer to your question (formulated above) is that usage decides, or in other words the particular language.

- Is there a simple concept or sentence that would clarify the difference? I'm guessing "I am" is the most confusing example.

This part of the question is founded on two acceptations of the verb "to be" and is not really relevant to the question of whether "here" is or not an adjective.
1  [V+adv/prep] to be located; to be in a place
2 as copular verb Having the state, quality, identity, nature, role, etc., specified. ([lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/be))

The second possibility makes for nonsense, only the first has meaning.

- Is it true that this applies to all/most location-related words? What makes location special? or is that just how the language developed?

Location is special in this respect that it does not "intrinsically" characterize something, whereas the adjective does. So, some languages at least developed along this logical line (English, French, German).

- Are there any other classes of words like this? I checked out time-related words, like "I'm early/late", but I think those are adjectives in that usage, is that right?

Yes, there are prepositions that are considered to be prepositions only marginally. In the words of CoGEL, "there are some words which behave in many ways like prepositions, although they have also affinities with other word classes such as verbs or adjectives".
Here are some of those from CoGEL, § 9.8.
  *bar, barring, excepting, excluding, save*
*concerning, following, given*

In this context, "*late*" and "*early*" are not adjectives but adverbs.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122711/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-why-are-location-words-like-here-adverbs-rather-th).

Answer (score -2):

> The am is indeed an auxiliary verb, meaning -- if anything -- 'be located (at)'.
>
> Executive Summary: Calling something an "adverb" is a confession of ignorance.
>
> https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111058/what-part-of-speech-does-here-have-in-i-am-here

Pace John Lawler I cannot agree with his claim.

“Here” = at this place.

“**At this place**” is clearly an adjunct.

I am here does **not** mean “I am this place” or “I at this place”

The point of saying “**I am here**” is **to announce your existence** “at this place” and thus:  “**I am here**” = **I exist at this place**, and **here** modifies “**exists**” adverbially. (See 3, below)

**Background.**

**Am** is part of the verb “to be.”

The verb “to be” stems from at least 4 Old English Verbs **eomon, sindon, beon/bion, weren** all of which had different meanings and it retains their meaning and uses:

**To be** can be

1 A copula indicating an equality/equivalence. Here, the verb is semantically empty: it may be replaced by “=”, i.e. the equals sign. “Two plus two is four”; “He is a policeman.”

2 (a future existential sense) To become or grow: “Wait until it is two metres [taller].”

3 Existential[1]: to live, exist, stay or remain in a place/condition/time, etc. (Compare: frambēon to be absent, away from (compare from prep., adv., and conj.))

*“I was in Paris for 4 years”; “In the swamp are Crocodiles”. “I am hot.”*

4  (a nuanced future existential sense) To arise, appear, come into being

1962   A. Moorehead “Blue Nile” 134   *Cairo from now on remained Mohammed Ali's home, the centre of the new empire to be.*

Comment: In "I am here", "here" is not an adjunct but a complement since it is required to complete the VP. Obligatory items are always complements.

Comment: @BillJ - can an adverb be a complement?

Comment: One or two verbs (like "treat") do select a manner adverb as complement, as in "He treated her **appallingly**". And adverbs can also occur as complement to "be" in its specifying sense, e.g. "The only way to do it is **very slowly**."

Comment: And hence "I exist here/at this place." -- *This species exists here and nowhere else.*

Comment: To say "I am here" is not to assert your existence at a place, but to assert your location. Whether "at this place" is an adjunct or complement depends on where it is within the larger structure it appears in.

Comment: In the weird "I exist here", "here" is obligatory for this sense of "exist", which means "located" / "live" / “reside”. Note you couldn’t say *I exist, and I do so here". And if you say "I exist", the verb has a different sense.

Comment: @BillJ *Note you couldn’t say *I exist, and I do so here"* I certainly could. *this sense of "exist", which means "located" / "live" / “reside* No, it's a little more subtle than that: it is in fact existential.

Comment: No it isn't, but in any case you're missing the point I'm making, which is about the contrast between complements and adjuncts. You clearly haven't grasped the difference between the two, since you haven't edited the glaring error in your answer. Again, in "I am here", "here" is **not** an adjunct (adverbial) but a complement since it is required to complete the  verb. Obligatory elements are always complements: they are needed to complete the verb phrase; optional elements may be either complements or adjuncts. Basic grammar, old boy.

Comment: @BillJ Your explanations are always entertaining. Is it possible for an adverb  / prepositional phrase to be a complement?